# PHP MVC Model with a method to fetch all of the model from database

Tags: object-oriented, php, mvc

I have a crazy question, consider I'm developing a blog website, There is two model named Post and Comment, now I wanna add a method to fetch all comments from database, which model should I choose to add this method to? Post or Comment.

Approach 1:

```
$post= new Post();
$post->setID($id);
$r = $post->loadAllComments();
```

Approach 2:

```
$r = Comment::loadAllComments($post_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use approach 2, putting it on the `Comment` model. I'd name the method something like `loadAllCommentsForPost` though, to clarify that it doesn't just load every single comment from the database.

Though approach 1 wouldn't be too bad, consider that you might have a lot more models relating to `Post` later on. You wouldn't want your `Post` model cluttered with methods like `loadAllLikes` and `loadAllRetweets`. It would be much cleaner to split those up to their respective models - `Likes` and `Retweets`.